# SQL wildcard _ in Linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have a query

```
select Max(CompanyId) from EmployeeCompany where CompanyId like '01-001' +'-___'
```

How can I implement '___'  in Linq any idea?
I have companiyId like 01-001-111, 01-001-112

Comment: What type of LINQ you are using? Is it Entity Framework, or you are querying objects in memory?

Comment: i am using linq to entities.

Answer (score 2):

With Entity Framework you can use [SqlFunctions.PatIndex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.patindex.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

```
  db.EmployeeCompany
    .Where(c => SqlFunctions.PatIndex("01-001-___", c.CompanyId) > 0)
    .Max(c => CompanyId)
```

NOTE: This function will not generate SQL query with LIKE operator. Instead it will generate query with PATINDEX function (which seems to be faster than LIKE operator).

Comment: *which seems to be faster than LIKE operator* very interesting... I didn't know...

Comment: I am getting this error "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method PatIndex method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression"

Comment: @MuzammilAnwar did you add using for `System.Data.Entity.SqlServer` namespace? And your code is exactly same as code in asnwer?

Comment: Thanks Sergey Berezovskiy it worked when I changed "System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions" to "System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlFunctions"